# how to send value(id) of clicked html tag to asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-post

I have Img tag on form  and I want to send the id of this to `aspx.cs`  . I used post method and retriving this id using `Request.Form["id"]`  but i'm not getting id on `aspx.cs` file .

**code:**

```
$("img").click(function () {
 var id = $(this).attr("id");// Here I am getting id How can i send this id to aspx.cs
 jq.post("WebForm1.aspx",
             id: $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Don't over use jQuery. `this.id` will bring you the `id`  easier and a lot faster than `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");// Here I am getting id How can i send this id to aspx.cs
        //alert(id); 
        jq.post("WebForm1.aspx", id: id);//this is enough
    });
```

Comment: Actually I can't see what did you fix in this answer? you just use the same value like he did.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with `this` getting over-written when you open the `post` method. Try:

```
$("img").click(function () {
      var my_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $.post("WebForm1.aspx", { id: my_id });
});
```

Alternatively, if you have several parameters to pass to the form, you could build your object ahead of time, like so:

```
$("img").click(function () {
      var params = {id: $(this).attr("id"), href: $(this).attr("href")};
      $.post("WebForm1.aspx", params);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{id: my_id }` ?

Comment: Yes, but I was copying and pasting the original example.

Comment: Fixed it.  Also closed the click method.

Comment: Looks like someone fixed it for me. I had a curly brace inside the method instead of outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").click(function () {
        var id = this.id; // No jquery needed!
        jq.post("WebForm1.aspx", {id: id});
    });
```

Don't over use jQuery. `this.id` will bring you the `id`  easier and a **lot faster** than `$(this).attr('id')`